# mysql - group already sorted result by date

Tags: mysql

**/edit**
Oh man, I'm so sorry guys. I didn't realize that my solution was basically correct - all I was missing was a second ORDER BY in the outer query.

---

I have two tables: a badge table with info about badges, and a user_award table with info about awards of badges to users. I want to get the X most recent awards and show an activity widget with pagination.

The thing is that admins can award a badge to multiple users at the same time. This creates an individual record in the table user_award for each user, but all with the same datetime value. In my activity widget I want to group all awards with the same datetime value in a single entry, so it would read like this:

- Bob and Mary received the badge "First in Line".
- Carlos received the badge "Night Owl".
- Jaime and Oliver received the badge "Kitchen Master"
- Neill received the badge "Already Up?".
- Bruce and Sylvester received the badge "Mortal Enemies".

As you can see, I don't want just the 5 most recent award entries, gut a grouping of the most recent award entries by date.

The relevant part of my schema is as follows:

```
user_award
  +---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
  | Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
  +---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
  | id            | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
  | user_ssomail  | varchar(64)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
  | badge_id      | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                | 
  | when          | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
  +---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


badge
+-------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| title                   | varchar(45)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| description             | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| image                   | varchar(120) | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
+-------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Sample data for the user_award table:

```
*************************** 13. row ***************************
 user_ssomail: aaa
     badge_id: 7
         when: 2013-01-02 18:29:16
*************************** 14. row ***************************
 user_ssomail: bbb
     badge_id: 4
         when: 2013-01-02 19:07:15
*************************** 15. row ***************************
 user_ssomail: ccc
     badge_id: 4
         when: 2013-01-02 19:07:15
```

The result I want to achieve is:

```
***result 1***
user_ssomails: bbb, ccc
badge_id: 4
when: 2013-01-02 19:07:15

***result 2***
user_ssomails: aaa
badge_id: 7
when: 2013-01-02 18:29:16
```

Note that awards with the same datetime are grouped, concatenating the user_ssomails.

From what I have learned so far, GROUP operations happen before SORT operations, so I tried a composite query. The inner query selects all user_awards and sorts them by date:

```
    SELECT badge.image,
       badge.title,
       user_award.badge_id,
       user_award.user_ssomail,
       user_award.when
FROM user_award
INNER JOIN badge ON user_award.badge_id = badge.id
ORDER BY user_award.when DESC
```

The outer query groups results by the datetime field:

```
    SELECT sorted_awards.image,
       sorted_awards.title,
       sorted_awards.badge_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(sorted_awards.user_ssomail) AS ssomails,
       sorted_awards.when
FROM
  (SELECT badge.image,
          badge.title,
          user_award.badge_id,
          user_award.user_ssomail,
          user_award.when
   FROM user_award
   INNER JOIN badge ON user_award.badge_id = badge.id
   ORDER BY user_award.when DESC) AS sorted_awards
GROUP BY sorted_awards.when LIMIT :bottom_limit,
                                  :upper_limit
```

But this doesn't return what I want it to. Can anybody point out what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use GROUP BY SORTED AWARDS. Grouping will give you just a single user, but you want multiple users. you would need a self join based on USER ID (not matching) and BADGE ID (matching)

Comment: Do you want the 5 most recent awards? Or the the awards made on the 5 more recent dates (which could be to more than 5 persons)?

Comment: @ypercube the 5 most recent dates, with all users that were awarded on these dates concatenated into a single result.

Comment: But they will may be awarded different badges, correct?

Comment: So, you want them all concatenated or one row per badge and datetime?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. The example I gave in the question is the following:

***result 1***
user_ssomails: bbb, ccc
badge_id: 4
when: 2013-01-02 19:07:15

***result 2***
user_ssomails: aaa
badge_id: 7
when: 2013-01-02 18:29:16

So two of the records get concatenated into one result because they have exactly the same datetime.

Comment: ah, goddamnit. I just realized that my solution was correct, all I was missing was a second ORDER BY in the outer query. My results were correctly assembled, I was just comparing the most recent award with what I got and saw that it wasn't correct, so I assumed my whole solution was flawed. But the info was correct, only in ascending chronological order. A second ORDER BY in the outer query resolved all issues.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just `GROUP BY` and then `ORDER BY`? The `LIMIT` is used with `ORDER BY` anyway:

```
SELECT b.image,
       b.title,
       a.badge_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(a.user_ssomail) AS ssomails,
       a.`when`
   FROM user_award AS a
     INNER JOIN badge AS b
       ON a.badge_id = b.id
   GROUP BY a.`when`, 
            a.badge_id 
   ORDER BY a.`when` DESC
       LIMIT x OFFSET y ;
```